# How to preserve utm parameters in wordpress website without plugin

Tags: wordpress, utm-tracking

My website is https://example.com/
When I run a campaign for example https://example.com/?utm_source=sourceexample&utm_medium=facebook

I want that when I navigate to any page the **?utm_source=sourceexample&utm_medium=facebook** should also propagate in the URL. Currently when I navigate to any other page or click on a link the UTM parameters disappear from the URL.

I was expecting some piece of code to put in the function.php file which should fix this issue but unfortunately I could not find it.
Please help me to achieve it.

Answer (score -1):

gravity from has this option inside the plugin.
will display on end page on what page they started.

also in google analytics.

Comment: Sorry we are neither using gravity form nor google analytics. We are using Matomo.
Once I did it for some other clients by using a piece of code in function.php
A similar example of the code is given below but it is for Polly language plugin.
function url_query_string( $url ) {
    if ( ! empty( $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] ) ) {
        return $url . '?' . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
    }
    return $url;
}
add_filter( 'pll_the_language_link', 'url_query_string' );